# Bluetooth connectivity to non iOS receiver

Tags: iphone, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can iPhone Bluetooth be connected to non iOS Bluetooth receivers? Or which Bluetooth receiver I can use to communicate my iPhone to external device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build one non-iOS bluetooth receiver that can communicate with iPhone/iPad on Classic Bluetooth (not Bluetooth 4.0 aka. Bluetooth Low Energy), you must get a MFi license for that (see [Apple MFi FAQs](http://mfi.apple.com/faqs)) and use the iOS accessory framework to carry out the connection. However, with Bluetooth Low Energy, Apple provides a very easy and open framework 'CoreBluetooth' to establish communications between iOS devices and BLE devices, no license is needed. This may probably because Apple doesn't have to worry about the energy consumption of BLE devices.